# Взаимодействие процессов через Pipe в Linux

Tags: linux, c, процесс, pipes

Задача такая: есть родительский процесс - сервер, и несколько клиентов-детей. Нужно, чтобы через пайпы клиент отсылал серверу сообщение, а сервер пересылал его остальным клиентам.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct client{
int fd[2];
pid_t pid;
};

int main(){
    fd_set  read_set;
    struct client clients[2];
    struct client servers[2];
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 2;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    int     i = 0;
    int     j = 0;
    int     k = 0;
    int     r = 0;  
    int     serverbytes;
    int     clientbytes;
    char    serverbuffer[80];
    char    clientbuffer[80];
    char    message[80];

    for(r;r<2;r++)
    {
    if(pipe(clients[r].fd) < 0)
        printf("pipe %i error \n", r);
    else
        printf("client pipe %i created \n", r);
    }
    r = 0;
    for(r;r<2;r++)
    {
    if(pipe(servers[r].fd) < 0)
        printf("pipe %i error \n", r);
    else
        printf("server pipe %i created \n", r);
    }

    clients[0].pid = fork();

    if(clients[0].pid != 0)
    {
    clients[1].pid = fork();
    if(clients[1].pid != 0){
            printf("server works. pid=%i \n", getpid());
            while(1){
            int maxfd = clients[1].fd[0];
            FD_ZERO(&read_set);
            FD_SET(clients[0].fd[0], &read_set);
            FD_SET(clients[1].fd[0], &read_set);
            int serverSelect = select(maxfd+1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            if(serverSelect != -1){
                for(k;k<2;k++)
                {
                    if(FD_ISSET(clients[k].fd[0], &read_set)){
                        serverbytes = read(clients[k].fd[0], serverbuffer, sizeof(serverbuffer));
                        printf("server receive: %s from client ID=%d \n", serverbuffer, k);
                        for(i;i<2;i++){
                            if(i!=k){
                                close(servers[k].fd[0]);
                                write(servers[k].fd[1], serverbuffer, sizeof(serverbuffer));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(serverSelect == 0)
                printf("select timeout \n");
            else
                perror("err");  
            sleep(5);
            }   
    }       
    else
    {
        sprintf(message,"child %d", 1);
        printf("client %i works. pid=%i \n", 1, getpid());
        //close(servers[1].fd[1]);
        //open(servers[1].fd[0]);
        //if(read(servers[1].fd[0], clientbuffer, sizeof(clientbuffer)) == -1){
            //printf("client %i read error \n",1);
        //}
        //else
           //printf("client %i receive %s \n",1,clientbuffer);
        //close(clients[1].fd[0]);
        while(1){
        write(clients[1].fd[1], message, (strlen(message)+1));
        printf("client %i send: %s \n", 1, message);
            sleep(3);
    }
        exit(0);
    }
    }
    else
    {
    sprintf(message,"child %d", 0);
    printf("client %i works. pid=%i \n", 0, getpid());
    //close(servers[0].fd[1]);
    //open(servers[0].fd[0]);
    //if(read(servers[0].fd[0], clientbuffer, sizeof(clientbuffer)) == -1){
       //printf("client %i read error \n",1);
    //}
    //else
        //printf("client %i receive %s \n",1,clientbuffer);
    //close(clients[0].fd[0]);
    while(1){
    write(clients[0].fd[1], message, (strlen(message)+1));
    printf("client %i send: %s \n", 0, message);
    sleep(3);
    }
    exit(0);
}
return 0;

}
```

Я делаю для каждого клиента два пайпа - для отправки на сервер и для получения с сервера. Проблема в том, что сервер не выполняет select c errno=2 (no such file or directory). Почему такая ошибка? Заранее спасибо.

UPD: после изменений от @avp и заворачивания процессов в бесконечные циклы (сама программа - некое моедирования чата) вывод программы:

```
client pipe 0 created  
client pipe 1 created  
server pipe 0 created  
server pipe 1 created  
client 0 works. pid=32663  
client 1 works. pid=32664  
client 0 send: child 0  
client 1 send: child 1  
server works. pid=32662  
server receive: child 0 from client ID=0  
server receive: child 1 from client ID=1  
client 0 send: child 0  
client 1 send: child 1  
client 0 send: child 0  
client 1 send: child 1  
client 1 send: child 1  
client 0 send: child 0  
client 1 send: child 1  
client 0 send: child 0  
client 1 send: child 1  
client 0 send: child 0
```

То есть сервер получает **один раз** сообщения от клиента, и после этого они крутятся. Почему только один раз?

Дочерние процессы так же должны получать от сервера перенаправленные сообщения, для этого все написано, но пришлось закомментить, так как в ином случае не работает даже основа... Понимаю, вопрос скорее всего глупый, но я только учусь писать под никсы.

Comment: А что может значить вот этот вызов?

      open(servers[1].fd[0]);

И ещё. Прикольно видеть 

      for(r;r<2;r++)

(это какой-то секретный ритуал?)

Comment: я, можно сказать, первый раз работаю с Си под никсы...поэтому да, прикольно. а насчет for не понял. open'ом я пытался переоткрыть дескриптор, но уже понял свою ошибку

Comment: А что касается for'а, то эти строчки идентичны:

     for(r;r<2;r++)
     for(;r<2;r++)

Comment: @alexlz, я работаю на .NET, поэтому для меня такая сигнатура необычна :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежде всего, select возвращает 0, если наступил таймаут (см. `tv` у Вас) и это нормально, т.е. `errno` в `select` не заполняется, а Вы на ноль  `select` не проверяете.

А также, лучше `tv` и `read_set` устанавливать каждый раз перед вызовом `select()`, т.к. они могут модифицироваться этим вызовом.

Исправьте и посмотрим, что получается.

При отладке печатайте побольше информации (getpid(), getppid(), коды возврата и т.д.).

Comment: @avp, спасибо за ответ. я исправил код в соответствии с Вашими замечаниями. теперь не вываливается с ошибкой, но все так же не работает. 

вывод:

client pipe 0 created
client pipe 1 created
server pipe 0 created
server pipe 1 created
client 0 works. pid=32533
client 1 works. pid=32534
client 1 send: child 1
server works. pid=32532
client 0 send: child 0

Comment: @Макс Жуков, посмотрите на 



        for(k;k<2;k++)
        {


очевидно, что при втором и всех остальных проходах `k` будет равно `2` и тело цикла не исполнится. Это очевидная причина, что Вы не видите реакции на `select()`.

Да и 

    if(serverSelect != -1){
        ....
   } else if(serverSelect == 0) 

выглядит нелепо (догадайтесь сами).

Что Вам мешает печатать результат вызова функции (которую Вы, кстати, **изучаете**) сразу после ее вызова. Потом ведь Вам самому будет проще разбираться в поведении программы.

--

Кстати, ненужные для процесса пайпы лучше закрывать в нем после `fork`

Comment: @avp, мда, за for и if мне стыдно. но: если я раскомментирую код в клиентах (чтение из пайпа, в который пишет сервер после получения сообщения как раз в этом цикле for) за исключением функции open(), которая тут явно не в тему, select() возвращает 0. следовательно, таймаут. на всякий случай попробовал увеличить до 5 секунд, но это несерьезно, да и результат тот же. 

Проблема, я так понимаю, в том, что клиент не может прочитать из пайпа. Скорее всего, это из-за функции close(). Поэтому вопрос: как переоткрыть пайп?

То есть, нечто такое:

open pipe
read from pipe
close pipe

Comment: @Макс Жуков, таймаут тут может и ни при чем, хотя его стоит переустанвливать **непосредственно перед** `select()`

    On Linux, select() modifies timeout to reflect the amount of time not slept;

Где у Вас клиент **читает** пайп, я не вижу.

--

Переоткрыть пайп **нельзя**. Идея в том, что нужно закрывать только то, что нужно, а код у Вас запутан до безобразия, выделите код клиента в одну функцию с нужными параметрами.

Вот Вы делаете pipe(servers[i].fd); Если хотите, чтобы сервер писал в него, а клиент читал, то после fork() сервер должен делать close(servers[i].fd[0]), а клиент ...fd[1].

Comment: @avp, разобрался. огромное спасибо Вам за точные ответы и терпение!